# Elements rendering outside of block 'a' tag

Tags: html, css

I have a series of `<a>` tags that are set to `display:block`.

These have a series of `<divs>` within them, eg:

```
<a href="#" class="sliderframe">
             <div class="container-caption">
                <div class="slider-caption">
                  <p>CAPTION</p>
                  <a href="#">SHOP ONLINE</a>    
                </div>
            </div>
 </a>
```

However, when the browser renders these the inner divs appear outside the A tag, eg:

```
<a href="#" class="sliderframe"></a>
    <div class="container-caption">
      <div class="slider-caption">
         <p>CAPTION</p>
         <a href="#">SHOP ONLINE</a>    
      </div>
    </div>
```

Would anyone know why this is happening?

The CSS:

```
.sliderframe
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 570px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesting an anchor tag within another anchor tag is illegal. Browsers will automatically correct this by moving the nested elements to the outside of the parent anchor tag.